# How to add space after constructor argument with Eclipse Formatter

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to setup the Eclipse Formatter to place a space before the closing parenthesis of constructor arguments.

For example, I would like this:

```
new ArrayList( 10 )
{
    @Override
    public String toString( )
    {
        return "baz";
    }
};
```

Not this:

```
new ArrayList( 10)
{
    @Override
    public String toString( )
    {
        return "baz";
    }
};
```

The relevant setting appears to be `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit... > White Space > Expressions > Function invocations > before closing parenthesis`.

If I don't create an anonymous class as above, checking this setting works fine, producing:

```
new ArrayList( 10 )
```

If unchecked:

```
new ArrayList( 10)
```

However that setting doesn't seem to apply with an anonymous class as above. Is there any way around this or is this a bug / limitation of the Eclipse Formatter?